# Register KeyDownHandler on GWT VerticalPanel

Tags: gwt, event-handling

I have a gwt VerticalPanel class that i need to handel KeyDown events for it.
the method i used to implement keyboard handler in my class is:
i add :

```
this.sinkEvents(Event.ONKEYDOWN);
```

to constructor
then i override method onBrowserEvent() to handle key down event.

```
 @Override 
public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onBrowserEvent(event);
  int type = DOM.eventGetType(event);
  switch (type) {
  case Event.ONKEYDOWN:
                        //call method to handle this keydown event
   onKeyDownEvent(event);
   break;
  default:
   return;

  }
 }
```

however this method doesn’t work for this VerticalPanel class.no KeyDown Event is fired when i press a key!

there are specific gwt widgets that support KeyDownHandler like Button etc..VerticalPanel is not one of them..so we need a work around to register a KeyDownHandler on a class extending VerticalPanel.
can you suggest an idea or hint?

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could create a `Composite` that wrappes a `FocusPanel` and a `VerticalPanel`. This way you can catch all key events provided the `FocusPanel` is focused. Simply delegate the needed methods to the panels:

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    ExtendedVerticalPanel panel = new ExtendedVerticalPanel();
    panel.add(new Label("some content"));
    panel.addKeyDownHandler(new KeyDownHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onKeyDown(KeyDownEvent event) {
            if (event.getNativeKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER) {
                Window.alert("enter hit");
            }
        }
    });
    RootPanel.get().add(panel);
}

private class ExtendedVerticalPanel extends Composite implements HasWidgets, HasAllKeyHandlers {

    private VerticalPanel fVerticalPanel;
    private FocusPanel fFocusPanel;

    public ExtendedVerticalPanel() {
        fVerticalPanel = new VerticalPanel();
        fFocusPanel = new FocusPanel();
        fFocusPanel.setWidget(fVerticalPanel);
        initWidget(fFocusPanel);
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Widget w) {
        fVerticalPanel.add(w);
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        fVerticalPanel.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Widget> iterator() {
        return fVerticalPanel.iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Widget w) {
        return fVerticalPanel.remove(w);
    }

    @Override
    public HandlerRegistration addKeyUpHandler(KeyUpHandler handler) {
        return fFocusPanel.addKeyUpHandler(handler);
    }

    @Override
    public HandlerRegistration addKeyDownHandler(KeyDownHandler handler) {
        return fFocusPanel.addKeyDownHandler(handler);
    }

    @Override
    public HandlerRegistration addKeyPressHandler(KeyPressHandler handler) {
        return fFocusPanel.addKeyPressHandler(handler);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Your question on how to prevent the browser from scrolling when the arrow keys are pressed. Here a small example that works for me:

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    ExtendedVerticalPanel panel = new ExtendedVerticalPanel();
    // make panel reeeeaally big
    panel.setHeight("3000px");
    panel.add(new TextBox());
    panel.addKeyDownHandler(new KeyDownHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onKeyDown(KeyDownEvent event) {
            if (event.getNativeKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_DOWN) {
                Window.alert("down hit");
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    });
    RootPanel.get().add(panel);
}
```

Add the handlers you need and call `preventDefault()` on the events the browser must not take care of.

Comment: yes perfect solution. i did in fact realized that FocusPanel was the solution by wrapping my VerticalPanel in a FocusPanel.However your code is very elegant. i liked the Idea of writing an ExtendedVerticalPanel . thanks much!

Comment: Hello, I have another question: When i register keyDownHandler for my ExtendedVerticalPanel and use Up/Down keys it scrolls the Browser Window scroller while firing key up/down events for my Panel. this behavior is not acceptable. I tried a fix by calling event.stopPropagation() at the begining of KeyDownHandler.onKeyDown(KeyDownEvent event) method. the problem is that stoping event propagation disables all key events for widgets inside my Panel like TextBox ect..How can i prevent browser window scroller to scroll while using key up/down on my Panel? thanks much.

Comment: yes i used preventDefault() and it also disables key events on the Panel. the TextBox that has keys disabled is inside a FocusPanel . could this be the problem? preventDefault() seems to cancel key events for all widgets inside the Panel. any idea what is going wrong? thanks much

Comment: thank you! I now managed to handle key events propagation properly. thanks much for great help!