# Can we add a ClickHandler and a KeyDownHandler to the same PushButton with an image? I get the click events but the key press event is not captured

Tags: java, gwt, event-handling

Simplified code

```
play = new PushButton("Play");
play.getUpFace().setImage(new Image(pathToImages+offImage));
play.getUpHoveringFace().setImage(new Image(pathToImages+hoverImage));

play.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                //This event is captured
    }
});
```

I require a keyboard button as a shortcut to play button accordingly I have added

```
Event.addNativePreviewHandler(new NativePreviewHandler() {
                    @Override
            public void onPreviewNativeEvent(NativePreviewEvent event) 
            {  //Call the functionality of play button for the approriate key press
            }
        });
```

But once I click the play button using mouse the above nativePreviewHandler does not capture the key press event from keyboard.

So I added a keyDownHandler to the play button

```
play.addKeyDownHandler(new KeyDownHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onKeyDown(KeyDownEvent event) {
                //This event is never fired
            }
        });
```

But the above onKeyDown() method is never called.

Only after I click at some other place on screen is the key press event captured by the nativePreviewHandler.

Just as additional info, I tried following without success

1. Added DomHandler to the play button instead of keyDownHandler
2. Removed the images set to the play button
3. Tried to unfocus the play button every time it is pressed using play.setFocus(false);

Any possible solutions or suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The play button need to have the focus in order to be able to catch the keyDownEvent.
Could you check this ?

If you can't set the focus on that button: [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4432966/1722236). You need to set a keyDownHandler to a container and ensure it is focused at all time in order to catch the events even if your button is not focused.

Comment: Thanks otonglet. The issue was with play button focus. Once I explicitly set focus on the play button, I was able to capture the event. I was assuming that clicking on the button with mouse automatically set the focus on the button but it was not so.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
Event.addNativePreviewHandler(new NativePreviewHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onPreviewNativeEvent(NativePreviewEvent event) {
        if (event.getNativeEvent().getType().equals("keydown")) { 
            Window.alert("Code: " + Integer.toString(event.getNativeEvent().getKeyCode()));
        }       
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks El Hoss, your code is right but my issue is with capturing of the even in addNativePreviewHandler. As the onPreviewNAtiveEvent() is not being called, I am stuck.